# Location using QR code in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code

I want to use QR code to get the smart phone's location (either UTM or Lat/Lon). Reading [this article](http://mirror2image.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/google-googles-qr-codes-localization/), it looks like it is possible to get the position of the smart phone. In addition, I want to render some 3D models on the camera screen. Is it possible? Actually I have no clue from where should I start.

Can anyone help me out regarding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you read that article carefully, all it suggests to get the location of the phone, is to simply encode the lat/lon in the QR code itself. This will only work if the location of the displayed QR codes are fixed (e.g. a sticker on a wall rather than printed on a flyer).

Is it possible to render 3D models on a camera screen? Sure. It wouldn't be the default camera app, you'd have to make your own. It would involve a fair bit of math if you wanted to position the 3D model relative to the QR code. You'd probably try to build planes based on the sides of the squares.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually ment would this be possible to render a 3D model on top of the QR code if it is saved in the server? Cause I was using NyARToolkit (Android version of ARToolkit) but it is unable to load different type of 3D models.